No apply button when creating table on MySQL Workbench
MySQL Workbench: 8.0.36
macOS: 14.4.1
When I created a table I can't find the apply button. Where the apply button was and where should I set the table name?


Does this answer your question? MySQL Workbench not showing Apply and Revert buttons while creating a table

I encountered the same issue, downloading 8.0.34 instead of 8.0.36 seems to fix the issue until they can actually patch it.  I'm running Sonoma as well so your OS version shouldn't be an issue.  Hopefully this will work for you as well.
